# Try to learn new script

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I have been set the task of making a online register system for a school to know who has arrived as well as a page to add students to a mysql database.

I need to use javascript to make a text area be displayed as well as having text areas un changeable until the edit button beside them has been clicked, once the button has been clicked I need the values to change to say done which when clicked will make them unchangeable again. Here is the jsfiddle:

> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IJustWantToMakeAWebsite/eFJZ6/6/)

Code:

```
<div id="addstudents">
    <form>
    Students Full Name:<input type="text" name="fullname"><input type="button" value="edit"><br>

    Students Form: <select name="form">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select><input type="button" value="edit"><br>

    Students Tutor Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><input type="button" value="edit"><br>

    Students Tutor Name: <input type="text" name="TutorName"><br>

    Disability: <select name="disability">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select><br>    

        <p>All the fields need to be locked until the edit button beside them is clicked. When the value of the disability is changed i need to text area to apear. All of this need to be done in java script.</p>
    </form>    


        </div>
    <div id="menu">
    this will be the menu area
    </div>
```

Comment: So, is that a fiddle link you want us to see? You have posted it in the weirdest way posible!

Comment: pm me and so i can learn it live using jsfiddle collaboration

Comment: yes i couldn't do it any other way it wouldn't just let me post the html or just link it

Comment: yes it would. I did it for you

Comment: You cannot `pm` in StackOverflow.

Comment: ok then i will post a link here in a minute for people to join

Comment: here is the jsfiddle collaboration  http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DHnpRsQOOH

Comment: I think you should really read throroughly [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). I'm saying this because StackOverflow is not a site where tell us what to do and expect people to do it. It's your assignment, so you should do it. Please, first learn javascript and come back when you find a particular problem that you cannot overcome. You are just asking for us to do your work.

Comment: Its not an assignment i am trying to learn and my friend is setting me tasks its not for real usage or a collage assignment

Comment: i just can't find the help i need online

Comment: I would just like to say thanks for the help some of you gave me and thanks for trying to help but it seems some people don't seem to understand that i am not in collage i am a teen trying to learn and just getting confused because i am dyslexic and don't understand the reams of information that you get when you google what you want all i was asking for was someone to show me so i can learn not do it for me as some people clearly thought. and i did read through the help Center when i first signed up but i had now where ells really to turn for help

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp

Comment: thank you ever so much i will read this now

Comment: Give the textfield an id. When the user presses the button get the textfield object using document.getElementById and set its readonlyness to false

Comment: Ok thanks For that link MistressDavid but how then can i make the button change back to make it unlock the box?

Comment: See my answer which i just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Give the input an id, like this:

```
 <input id="blah" readonly="true">
```

You will need the id later. And make it readonly.

2 Hook the button up to code like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="makeEditable()">
```

3 Write some code:

```
function makeEditable() {
    var text = document.getElementById("blah") //Id in step 1
    text.readonly = "false" //make it editable - see link
}
```

There you go!

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help

Comment: do you know how to use java script to hide a text area until they chose a spesific drop down option

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

Comment: Both links should help.

Comment: BTW if you dont want the elements to take up space, use display:none instead of visibility:hidden

Comment: Will do that thanks for the tip